# Vagrant + Drupal Running Extremely Slow

Tags: drupal, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using vagrant to host several environments. A few weeks ago, a power surge destroyed my VM which was working great. A backend developor built me a new Vagrantfile, but it has been insanely slow. Running `drush cc all` can take up to 10 minutes on the largest site that I support. I've tried numerous solutions, but none of them have helped. It would be worth noting that loading frontward facing pages is much faster than loading admin pages. Using drush and git is also extremely slow.

Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
          vb.memory = "4096"
    end

  # config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/var/www",

    # config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/sites/dev.query-auth", id: "vagrant-root"
    owner: "vagrant",
    group: "www-data",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]


  config.vm.provision "fix-no-tty", type: "shell" do |s|
    s.privileged = false
    s.inline = "sudo sed -i '/tty/!s/mesg n/tty -s \\&\\& mesg n/' /root/.profile"
  end

    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision.sh"

end
```

A common fix that I've seen is setting NFS to true, but it has no effect on performance. Any tips on how to improve my performance would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine, working pretty well. Try using it, or combine those 2.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.22"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is the path on the host to the actual folder.
  # The second argument is the path on the guest to mount the folder.
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/html", nfs: true

  # Define the bootstrap file: A (shell) script that runs after first setup of your box (= provisioning)
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"

config.vm.boot_timeout = 3000

 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  # v.gui = true
  v.memory = 3072
  v.cpus = 2
 end


end
```

Comment: Thanks, but aside from nfs being set to true, and you assigning two cpu cores, I don't see much of a difference. I've actually tried both of those options, and neither improve Vagrant's performance.

Comment: Hmm...then it's not about this configuration.